# Want to set the in/out points but modified the existing clip

Tags: premiere

I am new to Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2014. The source pane is in such a state:

[image]

and when I want to mark a new in point for a new clip, it will be like

[image]

which will erase one of the clips:

[image]

How to exit this "edit mode"? Thank you.

**Update**: if I right-click the source pane, I can see the "Clear In", "Clear Out", and "Clear In and Out" are greyed out.

Comment: And you are doing nothing else to tell it to perform a 3 point edit?  It just automatically happens when you set the third point?

Comment: @AJHenderson I am not doing a 3 point edit and just want to create a new clip from the source but it seems I can only modify the in/out point of some existing sequence. I also notice that the "Clear" family items are greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is they did some kind of ability to load a clip in to the source viewer to view the clip in it's entirety.  My expectation is that you need to load the clip from the project window in to the source window.  That should disassociate it from a particular edit.

Comment: Thanks, this works as a work-around. Do you know the name of this mode so that I can know more about it?

Comment: I don't think it is a special mode so to speak.  It is just allowing you to open a particular edit in the source window.  It's a bit of an odd thing to do, but my guess is they did it in a 3 point editing style to allow for sliding the end points of the edit more easily.  It's basically a more advanced version of the old sliding edit tool.